# Should there be a past perfect where its usage is concerned

Tags: past-perfect

A woman of about 40 who **(had)** called an uber, was surrounded by a group of men claiming she wasn't allowed to call an uber at the location, and must take a cab from the station.

Should the had be there?
Is the sentence okay either way?
Even if we didn't use the **had** there, the sentence would still remain chronological, so is the had necessary there?

Comment: Reinforcement, corroboration, intentional redundancy are not shortcomings in message-exchange and communication. Define "necessary".  Haven't you asked this same question about 1000 times now?

Comment: I know.
But since i'm applying for an internship in a magazine company, I need to be sure the sentences I'm constructing are not wrong, and are grammatically correct.
My sorry, if my asking the question time and time again bothers you. @TRomano

Comment: One begins to wonder if you have understood the answers you have been given, when you ask the same question over and over. *Stylistically*, the past perfect is better, in that it makes the sequence of actions clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The past perfect in this case makes the action be quite separated from the others.

When using the past simple, the time of the situations are normally clear.